# Bake with Direct and Indirect but without shadows ? (later exported to Davinci Resolve)

Tags: texture-baking

Using Blender 2.82

In the end i will be exporting to Davinci Resolve and doing my (main) lighting and shadowing there (so the camera work in Davinci casts the shadows at correct angles). I can not create the room textures i like in Davinci, so i will be using Blender.

As you can see in the image there is a room, sink and shelves (each there own objects). If i hide the sink and shelves, the wall texturing in Blender come out exactly as i want (lit but with no shadows) and i used that baked Diffuse image in Davinci.

The only way ive found not to have shadows (casted by sink and shelves) is by putting the objects into 'collections' and un-ticking the collection box. Ive tried hiding the objects via the eye button (hide/un-hide) but that dont work. Also under each objects 'Material -> Shadow Mode' ive tried setting to 'none' (which seams to work in Eevee) but does not in the Cycle engine when baking.

**My question**:
What is the best way to bake this so i can have the *lighting* from Blender, but without objects casting shadows. Even though my current method is working, it does not seam like the best/correct way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what i wanted to do.

While "in" the Cycles engine (option does not appear in Eevee), under:

Objects Properties -> Visibility -> Ray Visibility you can un-tick 'Shadow'

[image]